# How to fix openSUSE Tumbleweed Gnome freezing whenever disconnected from the bluetooth device Redmi Buds 4 3.0.3.4

Tags: bluetooth, freeze, gnome, connection, opensuse

I'm using a `VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X515EA_X515EA 1.0` running on `openSUSE Tumbleweed x86_64 kernel 6.3.9-1-default`. Connecting to my earbuds `Redmi Buds 4 3.0.3.4` with MAC Address `7C:C9:5E:6F:ED:A3` via `bluetoothctl` is buggy. When connecting to the earbuds for the first time after boot, it will only connect for a few seconds, then disconnect. If i'm not fast enough to reconnect, then my entire laptop freezes and I'd need to force shutdown before I could use it again.

These are what I got from my attempt of troubleshooting it:

**First time connection after boot**
After boot, I try to connect to my earbuds via `bluetoothctl` with these steps:

Manage Bluetooth devices from the command-line.

```
bluetoothctl
```

```
Agent registered
AdvertisementMonitor path registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 14:13:33:DA:C9:3E Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 7C:C9:5E:6F:ED:A3 Redmi Buds 4
```

Information about the earbuds using `bluetoothctl info`

```
[Redmi Buds 4]# info
Device 7C:C9:5E:6F:ED:A3 (public)
    Name: Redmi Buds 4
    Alias: Redmi Buds 4
    Paired: yes
    Bonded: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Unknown                   (0000fd2d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (8a482a08-5507-42ac-b673-a88df48b3fc7)
    ManufacturerData Key: 0x038f
    ManufacturerData Value:
  16 01 12 c1 6a 63 64 58 3e c9 da c9 7c 5e a3 ed  ....jcdX>...|^..
  6f c6 c9 7c 5e a3 ed 6f                          o..|^..o        
    ManufacturerData Key: 0x1727
    ManufacturerData Value:
  08 03 02 50 37 a3 ed 6f 5e 08                    ...P7..o^.      
    AdvertisingFlags:
  1a
```

Here are the bluetooth journal logs i via:

```
journalctl --since=today _COMM=bluetoothd > bluetooth_logs_today.txt
```

Link: https://pastebin.com/r4p0gkkV

```
journalctl -b -2 _COMM=bluetoothd > bluetooth_logs.txt
journalctl -b -1 _COMM=bluetoothd >> bluetooth_logs.txt
```

Link: https://pastebin.com/rpVtmfbZ

I've searched using DuckDuckGo for similar problems using the following queries:

- `bluetooth device disconnecting linux site:(reddit.com OR stackexchange.com OR superuser.com)`
- `troubleshooting bluetoothctl linux site:(reddit.com OR stackexchange.com OR superuser.com)`

Similar, but not the same cases as mine's

- [Bluetooth intermittently disconnects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602730/bluetooth-intermittently-disconnects)
- [Bluetoothctl connects and disconnects repeatedly](https://superuser.com/questions/1160934/bluetoothctl-connects-and-disconnects-repeatedly)
- [Bluetooth headphones disconnect after a few seconds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607286/bluetooth-headphones-disconnect-after-a-few-seconds)

I want it that when I connect to my bluetooth device, it won't disconnect a few seconds after I connect it, and for my laptop to not freeze whenever the bluetooth connection gets disconnected

**More Information About my Laptop**
Hardware Model: `ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X515EA_X515EA`
OS Name: `openSUSE Tumbleweed`
OS Type: `64-bit`
GNOME Version: `44.2`
Windowing System: `Wayland`
Kernel Version: `Linux 6.3.9-1-default`